# Xterm js + pty + websocket weird characters after reconnect

Tags: node.js, websocket, terminal, pty, xtermjs

I'm writing a web terminal for fun. I'm using xterm js + pty. I'm having a linux server, and the client uses websocket to connect to it. The websocket will send message to the server which will be sent to the terminal spawned by pty. Any output will be sent back via websocket to the client in the xterm. Everything works fine.

But in unstable network, I want to reconnect the websocket after disconnection. Here is how I handle it.

```js
function createWebSocket() {
  var socket = new WebSocket(socketUri);
  socket.onopen = handleSocketOpen;
  socket.onclose = handleSocketClose;
}

function handleSocketClose() {
  term.writeln("\n\r\x1B[1;31mTerminal was disconnected.\x1B[0m ");
  retryConnectClosedSocketOrCleanup(1);
}


    function retryConnectClosedSocketOrCleanup(retryCount) {
      // Get current term size.
      var method = 'POST';
      var geometry = term.proposeGeometry();
      var targetUri = consoleUri + '/terminals/' + termId + '/size?cols=' + geometry.cols + '&rows=' + geometry.rows;

      // Resize terminal to detect if the terminal exists on the server.
      $.ajax(targetUri,
        {
          method: method,
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          timeout: 3000
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

          // If resize failed with 4xx or 5xx, then there is no way to reconnect to the same terminal.
          // Do socket close clean up right away.
          if (jqXHR.status >= 400) {
            console.warn("Terminal failed to reconnect because the previous session no longer exists.");
            socketCloseCleanup();
            return;
          }

          // If resize failed with other reason, retry.
          retryCount = retryCount || 0;
          if (retryCount > maxRetrySocketConnectionCount) {
            term.writeln("\n\r\x1B[1;31mTerminal failed to reconnect after " + maxRetrySocketConnectionCount + " attempts. \x1B[0m");
            socketCloseCleanup();
          } else {
            term.write(retryCount == 1 ? "\n\r\x1B[1;31mReconnecting terminal.." : "\x1B[1;31m.");
            setTimeout(function () { retryConnectClosedSocketOrCleanup(retryCount + 1) }, retrySocketConnectionDelay);
          }
        })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          // If resize was successful, then the terminal still exists on the server.
          // Reopen socket.
          if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
            term.writeln("\x1B[1;32m Terminal reconnected.\x1B[0m ");
            term.fit();
            term.clear();
            term.eraseLine(0);
            createWebSocket();
          }
        });
    }
```

It also works fine in most cases. However, once I used "vi" or "vim", any following reconnect will result in some weird characters show up in the end.

[image]

I Googled a lot but didn't find much. The only thing I found is [here](https://github.com/saitoha/trachet/blob/master/trachet/seqdb.py), which looks like a bunch of error response from termcap.

**Follow up:**
I found the problem actually was from xterm js on the client side. Here is what I did:

I added console.log to xterm js attach addon to see if it’s xterm js that sent those characters first to the server after reconnection. And it turned out "yes". See in the console log.

[image]

After opening vim, I disconnected the internet. And this log appeared right after the reconnection. As you can see, the terminal (xterm js Terminal object) send to socket first with these characters and received back from the server via socket with the same thing.
I searched the code base of xterm js, it looks like these characters are generated from https://github.com/sourcelair/xterm.js/blob/42724c7f42f827d9e247d461066eb1506725e371/src/Parser.ts#L526-L535.

Any idea?

Comment: Does this happen when Vi is still open or even after closing it?

Also, can you please send a screenshot with the WebSocket frames sent to the browser after you reconnect?

Comment: Hi Paris, thanks for the response. I added a screenshot from the console log. It turned out it was xterm js on the client side sent those characters to the server first. I found a possible place in the xterm js git repo that looks like where it handles the parsing. Not sure if it's related or not.

Comment: do you have any public GitHub code of this to take a look?